# On some inequality (upper bound) on a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization

There is a problem (of physical origin) which needs an analytical solution or a hint.  Let us consider the following real-valued function of two variables

$y (t,a) = 4 \left(1 + \frac{t}{x(t,a)}\right)^{ - a - 1/2}  
  \left(1 - \frac{2}{x(t,a)}\right)^{ 1/2} (x(t,a))^{-3/2} (z(t,a))^{1/4} \left(1 + \frac{t}{2}\right)^{ a},$

where  $t  > 0$,  $0 < a < 1$ and

$x(t,a)   =   \frac{a-1}{2} t + \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z(t,a)}$,

$z(t,a)   =   (1-a)^2 t^2+ 2(3-a)t +9.$

It is necessary to prove  that

$$y(t,a) < 1$$

for all $t  > 0$ and $0 < a < 1$. The numerical analysis supports this bound.

P.S. I apologize for too ``technical'' question. It looks that the inequality is valid also for $a = 1$
but it fails for $a > 1$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a human verifiable proof.

The quadratic equation for $x$ in terms of $a,t$ is
$$
x^2-[(a-1)t+3]x+(2a-3)t=0
$$
Substituting $x=y+2$, we get
$$
y^2+[1+(1-a)t]y=2+t=1+\frac{T-a}{1-a}\tag{*}
$$
where $T=1+(1-a)t$ (I'm trying to mimic Mathematica explanation of proofs style). Thus $\frac{t}{2}+1=\frac{y(y+T)}{2}$.

Next, from the equation (*),
$$
t=\frac{(y-1)(y+2)}{1-(1-a)y}\,,
$$
so
$$
1+\frac tx=\frac{ay}{1-(1-a)y}
$$
Finally, from the OP equation for $x$, we get
$$
\sqrt z=2x-(a-1)t-3=2y+T\,.
$$
Plugging all that nonsense in, we see that we need to bound from above (by $1$ or better) the expression
$$
4\left[\frac{(y+T)(1-(1-a)y)}{2a}\right]^a
\left[\frac{(1-(1-a)y)}{ay}\right]^{1/2}\times
\\
\left[\frac{y}{y+2}\right]^{1/2}
\frac 1{(y+2)^{3/2}}(2y+T)^{1/2}
$$
Now, from $(*)$,
$$
(1-a)y(y+T)=1+T-2a\,,
$$
so the first bracket simplifies to
$$
\left[\frac{y-1+2a}{2a}\right]^a=\left[1+\frac{y-1}{2a}\right]^a\le 1+\frac{y-1}2=\frac{y+1}2
$$
(Here I use Bernoulli in the same way as Iosif did).
We can cancel $y^{1/2}$ and combine $y+2$'s, which leaves us with the factor
$$
F(T)=\frac{1-(1-a)y}a(2y+T)
$$
Here I'm going to use the symbolic differentiation tool:
$$
\frac d{dT}\log F(T)=-\frac{(1-a)\dot y}{1-(1-a)y}+\frac{2\dot y+1}{2y+T}\,.
$$
From $(*)$, we have $(1-a)(2y+T)\dot y=1-(1-a)y$, so the logarithmic derivative evaluates to $\frac{2\dot y}{2y+T}\le \frac{2\dot y}{2y+1}=\frac d{dT}\log(2y+1)$ (using $\dot y>0$ and equality for $T=y=1$, of course).
Thus $F(T)\le 2y+1$ and we end up with proving that
$$
2(y+1)\sqrt{2y+1}\le(y+2)^2
$$
However $(y+2)^2-2(y+1)\sqrt{2y+1}=\sqrt 2^2+(y+1-\sqrt{2y+1})^2$, which, according to the principle we discussed is trustworthy.

I leave the improvement of the last inequality to $2(y+1)\sqrt{2y+1}\le \gamma(y+2)^2$ with explicit $\gamma<1$ to Mathematica. Let me see if it is capable of that. But, of course, I want to see the full output, not just the declaration that the statement is true.

What I did doesn't go beyond the AI capabilities (just some bunch of random substitutions and symbolic manipulations). However, until I see a printout like this, I'll remain utterly skeptical. The fact that one of the most useful Mathematica commands for a friend of mine who is a big fan of it is "Quit kernel" doesn't add to my trust.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. However, I doubt that this proof "doesn't go beyond the [current] AI capabilities." :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks. But what I did here was exactly what, IMHO, a machine should do: apply random symbolic manipulations and see if the complexity of the formula goes down. It is like a chess game with a relatively simple evaluation function but computing a few steps (2 was enough here) forward before taking the minimax (or like gradient descent with occasional jumps). Anyway, I hope Matematica proved the sharp bound $\frac{\sqrt{3+2\sqrt 3}}{3}$ on fewer than 50 pages for you :-) As to the "use of our time", if we stop exercising our brains and bodies, our abilities decline. Continued

Comment: So I'm against self-driving cars, computerized proofs, etc. They are not bad if you need to do something quickly (though 1 hour for this problem was quick enough for me), but they should be used sparingly. And I find the time spent figuring out answers to other people questions better used than the one spent on the beach in Florida (another old-fashioned view). In a sense, that's what IMO our profession is: figuring things out for other people *regardless* of why they are interested in them. Plus we can play some games for ourselves too :-)

Comment: I like your idea of random substitutions, and I think MO is an addictive game. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need some time to verify all of that. The formula after the phrase "Plugging all that nonsense in, we see that our inequality is" needs adding " < 1". 
"

Comment: Also, it looks that   better  to use another letter, say u,  instead of y, to avoid the confusing with y(t,a).

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, indeed (about $<1$) I'll edit. I don't use $y$ in the original sense anywhere, so there should be no confusion there. And sure, check everything. The final sharp bound $\frac{\sqrt{3+2\sqrt 3}}{3}$ agrees with your numerical observations perfectly.

Comment: *"I need some time to verify all of that."* He-he. That is exactly what I have to say about all automated proofs. How were you going to verify those? :lol: I'm also curious: what came first, the quadratic equation for $x$ (or $y$) I wrote or your explicit formulas for $x$ and $z$? Part of the proof process looked like undoing what you've already done for the actual initial problem but I may be completely wrong here.

Comment: @fedja: About your phrase: "I'm also curious: what came first, the quadratic equation for x (or y) I wrote or your explicit formulas for x and z". Of course, the  quadratic equation came first (z is discriminant) .  Honestly speaking, both your proofs (by Iosif Pinelis and you) are looking rather unusual for me. But the idea to use the  convexity (originally proposed by Iosif Pinelis and later  used by you) looks as rather fruitful idea, while the appearance of T and F(T) in your proof looks as a rather unpredictable (and probably, not straightforward) step for me.

Comment: @Vladimir Yeah, the differentiation part is somewhat non-obvious. On the other hand, the definition of $F(T)$ itself is straightforward: everything else is expressed in terms of $y$ and $a$ only and has reasonable size, while this is the part that includes the (possibly very large) parameter $T$ and a factor that tends to $0$ as $T\to\infty$. $T$ is just the shortcut for the second coefficient in the equation for $y$: I'd rather have a one letter notation for it than for the right hand side. You can keep the original $t$ if you want, it does not change much, just the formulae get longer.

Comment: @fedja Probably, there is a typo after (*) - one should have $T = 1 + (1-a)t$.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, of course. I'll correct.

Comment: @Vladimir Still checking? Feel free to ask questions if something remains unclear :-)

Comment: @fedja I am very impressed by your proof, especially by a trick with logarithmic derivative.  It looks OK. I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\ty}{\tilde y}$With $x:=x(t,a)$, $y:=y(t,a)$, and $z:=z(t,a)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    y &= 4(1+t/x)^{-a-1/2}(1-2/x)^{1/2} x^{-3/2} z^{1/4}(1+t/2)^a \\ 
    &=4\Big(\frac{1+t/2}{1+t/x}\Big)^a(1+t/x)^{-1/2}(1-2/x)^{1/2} x^{-3/2} z^{1/4} \\ 
    &\le\ty:=4\Big(1-a+a\frac{1+t/2}{1+t/x}\Big)(1+t/x)^{-1/2}(1-2/x)^{1/2} x^{-3/2} z^{1/4}, 
\end{align*}
by the convexity of $u^a$ in $a$ for each real $u>0$.

Since $\ty$ is an algebraic function of $(t,a)$, it can be proved purely algorithmically that for all $(t,a)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,1)$ we have $\ty<1$ and hence $y<1$. Mathematica takes about 6 sec for this proof, which is a very long time for a computer program. In about 17 sec, Mathematica can also prove that $\ty<9/10$ and hence $y<9/10$. Below is the image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook; click on the image below to enlarge it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! As far as I understand such trick (with algorithmical proof) can not be applied to initial function y(t,a). Moreover, I have suspicion that it is possible to prove finer estimate by this method, say y(t,a) < 0.9    (numerical calculations say about the bound near 0.848 ).

Comment: Hmm... I enlarged but I still don't see the proof, just the expanded formula and the declaration that the result holds, which convinces me of pretty much nothing: the OP has already declared that the inequality holds himself... On the other hand, I'm an old-fashioned guy: I can sometimes trust software for algebraic identities but trusting it for inequalities defies my common sense :-).

Comment: @Vladimir : Indeed, if in the FindInstance command I replace ty[t, a] >= 1 by ty[t, a] >= 9/10, then I still get an empty set of solutions of the system of inequalities. NB: I previously used a wrong function instead of ty in my Mathematica notebook. With the correct function ty, the execution times are much greater.

Comment: @Vladimir : There is no algorithmic proof for the original function $y$, because it is not algebraic.

Comment: @fedja : I think we had a similar discussion before. :-) I will now respond to all your points. (i) Enlarging the **image** was not supposed to let one see details of the **proof**. (ii) The OP did not declare that the result holds; rather the OP said "The numerical analysis supports this bound." (iii) An algebraic inequality $a\ge b$ can be rewritten as the equality $a=b+c^2$ for some real $c$. So, if one is inclined to "trust software for algebraic identities", I see no reason not to trust it for algebraic inequalities.

Comment: @IosifPinelis (i) Have you seen the details yourself? (ii) And Mathematica just says "My program outputs true". What's the difference?  (iii) Indeed, if after some manipulations you get an algebraic representation $a=b+c^2+d^2+\dots$ for some explicit polynomials $a,b,c,d,\dots$, I would trust that it proves $a\ge b$ and the original inequality. But are you sure that that is what is going on behind the scenes? I'm sure that it is not, because the conditions $0<a<1$ have to be used, so factors of $a$ and $1-a$ are also needed and it all gets a bit trickier. Anyway, let me think about it :-)

Comment: The numerical analysis says that for fixed $a$ ($0 < a < 1$) the function $y(t,a)$  is 
monotonically increasing at interval $(0, t_0(a))$ to its maximal value 
$y(t_0(a),a) = y_{max}(a)$ and then it is monotonically decreasing at interval
$(t_0(a), + \infty)$ to asymptotical value  (which is a limit for $t \to + \infty$ ) 
$y_{\infty}(a) = \left(\frac{3 - 2a}{1 - a}\right)^{a - 3/2} 2^{2-a} < 1$.

Comment: (Continuation.) It looks (from numerical/graphical analysis) that the function $y_{max}(a)$ 
($0 < a < 1$) is monotonically increasing (in $a$) to $y_{max}(1-0) = 0.847...$, while
the function $y_{\infty}(a)$ is monotonically decreasing to $y_{\infty}(1-0) = 0$.

Comment: @Vladimir : I too had similar observations.

Comment: @fedja : Our discussion seems to be branching. So, I'll now address only some of your points. The double inequality $0<a<1$ can be rewritten as the system $a=b^2\ne0, 1-a=c^2\ne0$ of equalities and negations of equalities, or (say) as the system $a-a^2=b^2\ne0$. So, I still don't see any essential distinction between equalities and inequalities. As for seeing Mathematica's proofs, which it took seconds to produce and which apparently occupy tens or hundreds of pages, does anyone really want to see them, any more than to see the proof  that  (say) $\sin(1/137)>821/112478$?

Comment: Previous comment continued: In either case, we know that the corresponding algorithm is known, has been published, implemented in software, and tested a great number of times -- and this in most cases should be enough, I think. Of course, it is better to have a short, readable, and elegant proof. But is getting such a proof always the best use of our time? I think not always.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I tried to be as constructive in my criticism of the current state of AI as humanly possible: see my answer :-) Note: I am not saying that Mathematica is a bad thing. It is an excellent thing, just not really reliable (yet?)

Comment: @fedja : My own experience with Mathematica suggests that, despite occasional lapses, it is overall no less reliable than myself, even though most of my proofs can be checked by hand.

Comment: @IosifPinelis *Despite occasional lapses* is the key construct here and it should really be *despite occasional lapses that one has detected*. We have developed a totally unwarranted trust in the software capabilities that we also pass to the students. We doubt ourselves because we *know* ourselves well enough but we no longer really know the software we use and this lack of knowledge, instead of healthy skepticism, somehow produced blind confidence. You are reliable to me not because you don't err but because *I have ability to detect your errors* when they occur. Not so with the software.

Comment: @fedja : I don't think the trust in Mathematica's capabilities is "totally unwarranted". Indeed, I think a given proof in an average math paper is verified carefully by strictly less than one reader, on an average. I think usually we do not check all the details of a proof. Rather, we try to assess the plausibility of the final result and possibly intermediate ones. On the other hand, Mathematica's commands such as Reduce, FindInstance, and Maximize have apparently been tested at least thousands times.

Comment: Previous comment continued: The plausibility of their output can also be tested further, I think almost always, by numerical experimentation as well as by other software. In view of this, I think the output of Mathematica's commands such as Reduce, FindInstance, and Maximize is no less reliable than an average math proof, even when the latter has been read by one or two people.

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK, I take the words "totally unwarranted" back. You are right here. However, we are talking about 2 different types of reliability. The one you defend is that of  computation recipes of the Egyptian scribes with their famous "do so and you will be right" ending. They were also tested by millions of people for over 3000 years and the Egyptians were no fools or incompetent people. However, it was the new kind of reliability, that of a *verifiable argument* introduced by Greeks, that became the basis of all modern scientific progress.  Continued

Comment: In this respect, the average math. proof (even if you include all pathetic attempts at it of business calculus students into the averaging) is far more reliable to me than the output of the most sophisticated software written by the most intelligent people. It is something I can understand and learn some ideas from, which I can efficiently use in other situations even if the proof itself is flawed in some respect. The Matematica output has none of these properties. It is just like a bare answer to a problem in a textbook. The only thing it teaches is to go for a ready answer to that place.

Comment: @fedja : I think we are kind of repeating ourselves. (i) As I wrote before, I think in most cases we verify a proof by assessing its plausibility, rather than carefully checking all the tiny steps. Mathematica's proofs are therefore verifiable by numerics and/or by other software. (ii) We are talking here only about algorithmic proofs, which are routine and hence akin to a proof of (say) $\sin(1/137)>821/112478$. I think usually there is not much to learn from such proofs.

Comment: Previous comment continued: In this particular case, you yourself said that you obtained the proof by trying random substitutions and transformations, and that it is possible to teach a computer to construct such proofs. Suppose this has been done, and the resulting computer proofs are somewhat readable. Would one then want to read them? Would there be much to learn from those proofs?

Comment: @IosifPinelis The answer to both questions for me is "yes".  Do *you* still want to read my proof in this particular thread? Is there much to learn from it (not, perhaps, for you, but, say for Vladimir)? If your answers are "no", then we just hold different viewpoints here and there is nothing to argue about. But if they are "yes", then I do not see a big difference between learning from a human of from a machine. As to sin(1/137)>..., it is routine for me because I know Taylor series and can program the computation any time I want but it is a miracle for a precalculus student. Continued

Comment: The acceptance of output $X$ without running a verification scheme on it is an act of faith, IMHO, and the whole pre-Greek mathematics was a religion rather than science. Unlike Christianity or Islam, it was a sound religion with high practical value, but it was based of faith (and I do not think I'm repeating myself here). The other point is that we are mortal. The routine proofs cannot be completely delegated to machines once we can do it because every new generation has to learn them before they can do non-routine ones like you cannot abandon learning and practicing addition table by kids.

Comment: The algorithmic proofs are not routine either. The full proof tree includes the theory of the corresponding algorithm and the theory behind the code. Their acceptance without an act of faith is thus very time consuming and possible for only a few people (none in the Mathematica case because the code is not open source). And acts of faith is something I'm trying to reduce to the bare minimum while the society tries to maximize them. Ever thought of why the routine check of the consistency of the software output by increasing the tolerance level is not automatic and left to a human operator?

Comment: @fedja : I am glad that we have finally touched on the two cornerstone  questions where our answers disagree. To me, in principle, the proof is done where it is reduced to algorithmic proofs, provided that such proofs are feasible with commonly available computer resources. As for "acceptance without an act of faith", to me it is clear that such acceptance never exists. Even if I myself wrote a proof, and if it has been verified carefully by me and a number of other people, it is never certain that the proof is entirely correct.

Comment: Previous comment continued: I even think that it is no more certain than an average output of the Mathematica command Reduce (say), tested a great many times. Also, I don't think that the full proof tree is very relevant here, not any more than going back to foundations of mathematics every time we need to prove something like $\sin(1/137)>821/112478$. Because our resources are limited, we have to choose where to apply them. I don't think simplifying/understanding algorithmically available proofs is usually a good target for our efforts.

Comment: Previous comment continued: I did read your proof, for two reasons: (i) because it was written by you, whom I know as being able to produce ingenious proofs and (ii) because at first I did not believe that you just tried random substitutions and transformations (and which I don't quite believe now). I did not check all the details in your proof, because my experience suggests that you rarely make mistakes. So, faith was definitely involved there.

Comment: @IosifPinelis *To me, in principle, the proof is done where it is reduced to algorithmic proofs, provided that such proofs are feasible with commonly available computer resources.* Yep, we finally found our divergence place. For me, the proof can be accepted only when I verify all details. I can mistake in the verification process, of course, and I may be not capable of carrying it out, but without it I accept nothing. That attitude extends beyond mathematics as well. Your point of view is valid but I certainly would not recommend anybody without good proving and programming skills exercise it

Comment: We, probably, also diverge on one more thing: your point of view presumes that the ultimate goal is to establish the validity of the result and the means do not matter as long as they are legitimate, while my opinion is that the ultimate goal is to figure out how things can be done quickly and efficiently, and the particular results do not matter at all. From this point of view my lack of interest in $\sin()>$ comes only from my inability to go beyond the Taylor expansion idea but if you show me how it can be done faster, I would be most interested.

Comment: And finally, about the acts of faith: yes we are forced to commit them 99% of the time and the reduction is possible by only 1% at best, but this 1% is crucial in raising the awareness of the difference between an act of faith and act of (subjective) verification and that 1% is where all one's beliefs, prejudices, and opinions should really come from, IMHO, though, of course, one would have to extrapolate wildly on many issues. But that is just a personal point of view.

Comment: @fedja : I don't disagree with you on the 99% vs. 1%.

Answer (score 1):

*a human verifiable proof*:

Let us prove that the sharp bound of $y$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3+2\sqrt 3}}{3}$.

Letting $x := x(t, a), z := z(t, a), y := y(t, a)$, we have
$$y = 4 \left(\frac{1 + t/2}{1 + t/x}\right)^a\cdot \left(\frac{z}{(1 + t/x)^2}\right)^{1/4} (1 - 2/x)^{1/2} x^{-3/2}. \tag{1}$$

Using Bernoulli inequality $(1 + u)^r \le 1 + ru$ for all $r \in (0, 1]$ and all $u > -1$, we have
$$y \le 4 \left(1 + \left(\frac{1 + t/2}{1 + t/x}  - 1\right)a\right)\cdot \left(\frac{z}{(1 + t/x)^2}\right)^{1/4} (1 - 2/x)^{1/2} x^{-3/2} \tag{2}$$
and
$$y^2 \le 16 \left(1 + \left(\frac{1 + t/2}{1 + t/x}  - 1\right)a\right)^2\cdot \left(\frac{z}{(1 + t/x)^2}\right)^{1/2} (1 - 2/x) x^{-3}. \tag{3}$$

We first simplify the expression. We have
$$a \in (0, 1) \quad \iff \quad a = \frac{1}{1 + s}, \quad s > 0. $$
Then, we have (the so-called Euler substitution)
$$t > 0 \quad \iff \quad t = \frac{2(1+s)(3s+2 - 3u))}{u^2 - s^2}, \quad s < u < s + \frac23. $$
With these substitutions, we have
$$z = \left(\frac{-3u^2 + (6s + 4)u - 3s^2}{u^2 - s^2}\right)^2$$
and
$$x = \frac{6s + 2}{u + s}.$$
Then, (3) is written as
$$y^2 \le {\frac { \left(-3u^2 + 6su + 4u - 3s^2 \right)
        \left( 5\,s+2 - u \right) ^{2}}{4 \left( 3\,s+1 \right) ^{3}}}.
$$
The constraints are: $s > 0$ and $s < u < s + \frac23$.

We have
$$\sup_{s> 0, ~ s < u < s + \frac23} {\frac { \left(-3u^2 + 6su + 4u - 3s^2 \right)
        \left( 5\,s+2 - u \right) ^{2}}{4 \left( 3\,s+1 \right) ^{3}}} = \frac{3 + 2\sqrt 3}{9}. \tag{4}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

Thus, we have
$$y \le \frac{\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt 3}}{3}.$$

On the other hand, in (1), letting
$t = 3 + 3\sqrt 3, ~ a = 1$,
we have $y = \frac{\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt 3}}{3}$.
Thus, $\frac{\sqrt{3 + 2\sqrt 3}}{3}$ is a sharp bound.

We are done.

---

*Proof of* (4):

Fixed $s > 0$, let
$$f(u) := {\frac { \left(-3u^2 + 6su + 4u - 3s^2 \right)
        \left( 5\,s+2 - u \right) ^{2}}{4 \left( 3\,s+1 \right) ^{3}}}.$$
The maximum of $f(u)$ is attained
at $u_0 = 2\,s+1- \frac13\,\sqrt {9\,{s}^{2}+12\,s+3}$. Let
$g(s) := f(u_0)$.
It is easy to prove that $g'(s) < 0$ for all $s \ge 0$.
Thus, $g(s) \le g(0) =  \frac{3 + 2\sqrt 3}{9}$.

We are done.